# How to output in file uchar?

Tags: c++, qt

I have array of **unsigned char[128]** *= {0xFF, 0xBE,...0x99};*. And need to output it to **.txt** or **.bin** file. But all fuctions that I tried could work only with **const char***. 
So, what should I use to output uchar[]?

I tried fstream and QFile.

```
                             //  1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12    13    14    15    16
static uchar headerFile[128] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,   //1
                                0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,   //2
                                0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,   //3
                                0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,   //4
                                0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,   //5
                                0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,   //6
                                0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,   //7
                                0xFF, 0xFF, 0x47, 0x01, 0x84, 0x75, 0x00, 0x00, 0x39, 0xC2, 0x3A, 0xBE, 0xC3, 0x72, 0xC4, 0x71,}; //8

int main()
{
    QFile out("D:/DataOutput.bin");
    if( out.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly ) ) {
            out.write(&headerFile[0],128);
    }
}
```

UPD: Delete loop.

Comment: why do you need this for loop? Im suspecting that you need just: `out.write(headerFile, sizeof(headerFile));` (no loop).

Comment: out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(headerFile), 128);

Comment: The word is `array`, not `massive` (the latter means "huge")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&headerFile[0]), 128);
}
```